# Проблема с десериализацией массива строк из JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json

Мне нужно десериализировать объекты JSON в `object`.

```
class JsonRecord
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Date")]
        public string date = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Windows account")]
        public string windowsAccount = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Titles")]
        public string[] title { set; get; } 
    }
```

Данные беру из файла:

```
{
  "date": "22.05.2018 1:53:37",
  "windowsAccount": "DNAPC\\Администратор",
  "title": [
    "System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll",
    "System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll",
    "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll",
    "System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll"
  ]
}
```

Основной код:

```
string jsonString;
using (StreamReader sw = new StreamReader("History deleted files/history.json", System.Text.Encoding.Default))
{
    jsonString = sw.ReadToEnd();

}
JsonRecord jR = new JsonRecord();
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
jR = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonRecord>(jsonString); 

Debug.WriteLine(jR.windowsAccount);
```

`date` и `windowsAccount` могу получить, но массив строк `title` возвращает `null`.

Как исправить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Titles")]
```

на

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
```

Comment: Да, работает. Спасибо. Только не понимаю почему date и windowsAccount я в даном случае не зависит от этого атрибута, а массив строк зависит

Comment: @VLAD ещё как зависит. Попробуйте лишнего текста в те аттрибуты написать :)